# Show custom MapIcon for WPF MapControl

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, bing-maps

I would like to display a customized map icon within a .net core 3.1 WPF application.
I added the NuGet Package `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls` and put the MapControl on the MainWindow.

```
<map:MapControl x:Name="myMap" Loaded="OnMapLoaded" />
```

In the code-behind file I add a mapIcon to the `MapElements` collection and set the Image to a mapIconStreamReference.

```
private void OnMapLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var position = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = Latitude, Longitude = Longitude });
    MapIcon mapIcon1 = new MapIcon
    {
        Location = position,
        Image = mapIconStreamReference,
    };
    myMap.MapElements.Add(mapIcon1);
}
```

I tried to initialize the stream reference through different ways:

```
// load by WPF pack URI:
mapIconStreamReference = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Assets/MapPin.png"));

// load by UWP pack URI
mapIconStreamReference = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/MapPin.png"));

// load file into a memory stream
var fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"Assets/mappin.png");
var memStream = new MemoryStream();
fileStream.CopyTo(memStream);
mapIconStreamReference = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(memStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
```

The image is either declared as Resource or Content (I tried all combinations).

Whatever I try the map only displays the orange default map pin. The same code works properly within an UWP application. As I understand the MapControl from the toolkit is just a wrapper around the UWP MapControl shown in a XAML island.

Comment: I'm not sure what might be happening here. Have you verified that the stream is readable at the time it's assigned to the MapIcon, and is not disposed before the asynchronous call to add the MapIcon completes? The stream is read from a background thread and so needs to be available for some time after the Add call.

Comment: @DuncanLawler Good point, but I don't think that the stream will be disposed. mapIconStreamReference is a member of the class and should keep the reference. I changed my code so that the MemoryStream is also a class member and won't be disposed.